# How to fix classpath.txt in the startup directory no longer supported warning?

Tags: java, spring-boot, matlab, maven, classpath

I've created a Spring Boot Java project and I use Matlab (9.4.0.949201 (R2018a) Update 6, Java 1.8.0_144-b01). After finding the true version for the project (before this I got the "version of MATLAB Java Package that is not compatible with the version of MCR" error, to solve this problem I've changed my version of Matlab. R2023a -> R2018a). After changing the version of Matlab, some errors were fixed. However, I got this error right now.

```
Warning: classpath.txt in the startup directory no longer supported. See <a href="matlab: helpview([docroot '/techdoc/matlab_external/matlab_external.map'],'java_static_path')">The Static Path</a>.
```

This is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <start-class>peridynamics.demoApp</start-class>
       <cholSolver.path>C:\Users\user\Desktop\PDTO\pdtopolys\cholSolver.jar</cholSolver.path>
        <javabuilder.path>C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar</javabuilder.path>     
         
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>mtj</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version> 
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>    
   
    <!-- Replace hard-coded paths with variables   -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>peridynamics</groupId>
        <artifactId>cholSolver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${cholSolver.path}</systemPath>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mathworks</groupId>
        <artifactId>javabuilder</artifactId>
        <version>R2018a</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javabuilder.path}</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>peridynamics.demoApp</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>
             
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>      
</project>
```

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: Before adding Spring Boot Maven, the jar file was built successfully. After that, I got this error. Should I change the Spring Boot/Maven version or something?

Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.9.4 (dfbb324ad4a7c8fb0bf182e6d91b0ae20e3d2dd9)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.4
Java version: 11.0.19, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Can you share the github link to the project ?  it will be more time safer and i will give an answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I can not share the project due to privacy. If you recommend something, I can try it.

Comment: So seeing as you ran javac, I guess you are a beginner. You basically use build tools to package and compile your code. Maven is one such build tool, gradle is another. You basically want to run mvn clean package to create a jar file for your project, or mvnw clean install if you dont have maven on your system and are dependent on the bundled maven from spring starter.

Reference for maven for you to go through: https://www.baeldung.com/maven

Comment: if you will execute `mvn clean install` , will it help you to solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner.  For being more clear i tried to follow this steps: [link](https://dev.to/rohitk570/create-an-executable-jar-file-on-vs-code-n-command-line-154b). But I couldn't create .class files with javac.

Comment: @AndreiLisa i am gonna try, thank you.

Comment: if that doesnt work, then do try `mvnw clean install`

Comment: @AndreiLisa after installation i get build failure.

Comment: Can you update the question with the stack trace ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa I got `version of MATLAB Java Package that is not compatible with the version of MCR` error after I've checked them. I couldn't find a problem with this.

Comment: You should read the docs and so you will be able to set compatible versions of libraries

Comment: @AndreiLisa I've checked for Matlab version and MCR version in the Matlab app, and they are compatible. I don't understand why I'm getting this error.